post method not allowed using Django REST Framework API Key
    def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Override the default permissions for the view.
        """
        try:
            if 'bot' in self.request.path:
                print(f'post cheque')
                return [HasAPIKey()]
            # Return the custom permission classes for the current action.
            return [permission() for permission in self.serializers_permission_by_action[self.action][1]]
        except KeyError:
            # If the current action is not found in serializers_permission_by_action,
            # default to using the standard permissions.
            return super().get_permissions()


api_key1 = 'YOtxWIRR.OGgGvTaND1OEKJYvDtLAmBnR8tFFFTxz'
headers = {'X-Api-Key': api_key1 }



#view code

class ChequeViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Cheque.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChequeUpdateSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['cheque_number', 'sequence_number', 'status', 'todo']

    serializers_permission_by_action = {
        'list': (ChequeSerializer, 
                    []),
        'retrieve': (ChequeSerializer, 
                    []),
        'create': (ChequeCreateSerializer, 
                    [ ]),
        'update': (ChequeUpdateSerializer, 
                    []),
        'put': (ChequeUpdateSerializer, 
                    []),
        'partial_update': (ChequePatchSerializer, 
                    []),
        'destroy': (ChequePatchSerializer, 
                    []),
    }


def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        """
        create method used by BOT need to expose this api 
        with different authntication
        """
        try:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            if not serializer.is_valid():
                return Response(
                    {"status": "fail", "message": serializer.errors},
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )

            validated_data = serializer.validated_data
            session_object = validated_data.pop('session', None)
            session_id = session_object.id if session_object else None
            if not session_id:
                return Response(
                    {"status": "fail", "message": "Session object not found."},
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
            result = process_cheque_task.delay(
                validated_data=validated_data, 
                pdf=request.FILES['file'].read(), 
                session_id=session_id,
                )
            return Response(
                {"status": "success", "message": "Cheque information sent to processing queue."},
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response(
                {"status": "error", "message": "An error occurred during cheque creation."},
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )


#urls
router_with_bot.register('', ChequeViewset, basename='cheque')
router.register('', ChequeViewset, basename='cheque')
path('', include(router.urls)),
path('bot/', include(router_with_bot.urls)),

Method post not working in the DRF API Key
i am getting the results for get method
but for post method it is saying method not allowed
i am using model.viewset set and register the view with 2 endpoint one with bot in path and other without bot in path
end point with bot in path should only have the hasapikey permssion
and other end point may be have multiple other permission
that is my goal
but i am only getting the get request to work for end point with bot
post method seems  to not work

Post code of the view you're trying to call.

ok i will add the details above
